# Mongoose JS - Populate method not returning full referenced object... - Only returning objectId version

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, database

When I use the populate method, I am still only getting the _id.

Here is the controller I want this to take place in:

```
show: function(req, res) {
User.findOne({
  _id: req.params.id
})
.populate("roommates")
.exec(function(err, user) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    res.json(user.roommates)
  }
})
```

}

Here is my User model, with roommates reference at the very bottom:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter a username"],
    minlength: [6, "Username must be at least 6 characters"],
    maxlength: [15, "Username cannot exceed 15 characters"],
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter a password"],
    minlength: [6, "Password must be at least 6 characters"],
    maxlength: [17, "Password cannot exceed 17 characters"],
  },
  roommates: [{roommate: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"}, status: {type: String, default: "pending"}, requests: [{description: String, amount: Number}], balance: Number}]
})
```

What gives? I've gotten this populate method to work before in a different app, but it's not giving me the referenced objects back, just the normal object as it exists inside the array without it's essential user details.

Here's the response.. but that _id should populate into an objetx with other properties like a name etc...:

```
   [
  {
    "_id": "57f17d5f51cdcb0b5cefe74d",
    "balance": 0,
    "requests": [],
    "status": "pending"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the `roommate` field within the `roommates` array that's the reference in your schema, so you need to use dot notation in your `populate` call:

```
User.findOne({
  _id: req.params.id
})
.populate("roommates.roommate")
.exec(function(err, user) { ...
```

Comment: But sir the weirdest thing is happening. What you just suggested is not working, however what DOES work is using "roommates._id". Any explanation on this please? This confuses me. Maybe even though "roommate(singular)" is the one with the ObjectId reference, since it is nested inside "ROOMMATES",  all you have to do is say "roommates._id" and it knows that one of those properties inside "roommates" has an object reference??? I don't understand why this is working when I use "roommates._id"

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. I think we'll need to see a [MCVE] to help you figure this out.